# arduino on / off NON momentary switch implementation assistance

Tags: c++, arduino, switch-statement

I am new to programming and Arduino.
Board - ESP8266 Nodemcu pinout as below,

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is send a command based LOW/HIGH value from pin 0.
A two leg switch's one leg is connected to D3 (GPIO0 and in program 0) and other to ground.

The code I am trying is below,

```
#include<BitsAndDroidsFlightConnector.h>

BitsAndDroidsFlightConnector connector = BitsAndDroidsFlightConnector();

const byte exampleButtonA = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(exampleButtonA, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
   byte exampleButtonAvalue = digitalRead(exampleButtonA);   
   switch(exampleButtonAvalue)
    {
      case LOW:
        Serial.println("ON IT IS");
        break;
      case HIGH:
        Serial.println("OFF IT IS");
        break;
      default:
        Serial.println("error!");
        break;
    } 
}
```

Issue I am facing is, when I flash this program, Based on physical switch on or off
It continually prints either "ON IT IS" or "OFF IT IS"
The break is really not happening. I only want it to execute once.

I also tried this with if else and face same problem of repeated printing.

```
#include<BitsAndDroidsFlightConnector.h>

BitsAndDroidsFlightConnector connector = BitsAndDroidsFlightConnector();

const byte exampleButtonA = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(exampleButtonA, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
   if(digitalRead(exampleButtonA) == LOW){
    Serial.println("ON");
    delay(200);
   }
  else {
   Serial.println("OFF");   
   delay(200);
  } 
}
```

Any assistance?

Comment: It is ESP8266 Nodemcu, one leg of the switch is connected to D3 (GPIO0) and other to GND.  https://i2.wp.com/randomnerdtutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/ESP8266-NodeMCU-kit-12-E-pinout-gpio-pin.png?quality=100&strip=all&ssl=1

Comment: and it changes between ON and OFF while you don't touch the button?

Comment: No, it change only when move the switch to on and off position. Issue is, if I move to ON position, it does the Action (in this case serial print) endlessly, same when the position is OFF.

Comment: then it works as it should. the loop() loops

Comment: how can i make it do only once?

Comment: do what once? ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see message only once you need to write youre code in setup() section.
All code in loop() section is repeated in loop.

Replace you code with this:

```
#include<BitsAndDroidsFlightConnector.h>

BitsAndDroidsFlightConnector connector = BitsAndDroidsFlightConnector();

const byte exampleButtonA = 0;
int exampleButtonAvalue = 0;
int saved_exampleButtonAvalue = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(exampleButtonA, INPUT_PULLUP);

}

void loop() {
    exampleButtonAvalue = digitalRead(exampleButtonA); 

    if (exampleButtonAvalue != saved_exampleButtonAvalue){
        if(exampleButtonAvalue == LOW){
            Serial.println("ON");
        } else {
            Serial.println("OFF");   
        }
        saved_exampleButtonAvalue = exampleButtonAvalue;
    }

    delay(200);
}
```

Comment: But I want to my program to send command (in this case serial print) whenever I toggle the position of the switch. Ultimate goal is, using #include<BitsAndDroidsFlightConnector.h> I want that switch to toggle parking brake on or off based on switch position in Flight Simulator 2020.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick.